# Enable floatingFilter in autoGroupColumn

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

How to enable floatingFilter in autoGroupColumn's header cell?

Seems like this is not enough:

```
autoGroupColumnDef: {
        resizable: true,
        cellClass: 'group-row-cell col-number-1',
        headerClass: 'head-number-1',
        cellRendererParams: {
            suppressCount: true
        },
        suppressMovable: true,
        floatingFilter: true
}
```

All headers contain floating filter element except the autoGroupColumn

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `field` in `autoGroupColumnDef`, otherwise the grid won't know what to filter by.

Take a look at [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/3tLLgNWEX5bWUOob) Plunker example.